# Where to put FirebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged call in Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

What is the appropriate place for adding a call to initialize a global listener in Angular app?

Here is the code:

```
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private store: Store<fromAuth.State>,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth
  ) {
    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(payload => {
      if (payload) {
        const user: UserBeta = {
          uid: payload.uid,
          displayName: payload.displayName,
          email: payload.email,
          emailVerified: payload.emailVerified
        };

        this.store.dispatch(AuthActions.authenticated({ user }));
      } else {
        this.store.dispatch(AuthActions.notAuthenticated());
      }
    });
  }
```

As you could see I've added it to the constructor of the `AuthService` but it doesn't seem right for me.

What I'm also concerning about is that the following code has two dependencies: `Ngrx` and `AngularFireAuth`.

In this case, would it be correct to move somewhere to the `FirebaseModule` (i.e. firebase.module.ts) and if yes, how is the call will look like?

Comment: I have struggled so much with this issue. I ended up waiting in the component where I needed to check for a user to make sure that I get the result of user. The constructor can be tricky in my experience. I just made a normal method in the service and subscribe to it in the necessary components. It is really hard to have something globally.

Comment: Yeah, seems like `ngOnInit` of the `AppComponent` should be the case

Answer (score 1):

You can add it inside `ngOnInit()`, from the docs:

> A callback method that is invoked immediately after the default change detector has checked the directive's data-bound properties for the first time, and before any of the view or content children have been checked. It is invoked only once when the directive is instantiated.

Check here for more info:

https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit

Answer (score 0):

Thank all of you for replies.

I've finally decided to introduce a new `initialize()` method inside the `AuthService` and call it inside the `ngOnInit()` method of the `AppComponent`.

**auth.service.ts**:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private store: Store<fromAuth.State>,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth
  ) { }

  initialize() {
    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(payload => {
      if (payload) {
        const user: UserBeta = {
          uid: payload.uid,
          displayName: payload.displayName,
          email: payload.email,
          emailVerified: payload.emailVerified
        };

        this.store.dispatch(AuthActions.authenticated({ user }));
      } else {
        this.store.dispatch(AuthActions.notAuthenticated());
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.initialize();
  }
}
```

**Update**: At my project I'm using `ngrx` for state management. Since `AngularFireAuth` also manages user information I've faced difficulty in managing the same state in multiple places, which increased the complexity, so the final solution became quite complicated. In the end, I've decided to stop using the `onAuthStateChanged` listener and start persisting the `ngrx` state locally.